# Separating Mesh

Tags: algorithm, 3d, geometry

I've a problem with separating meshes. There is a combined mesh which has 1 vertex buffer and 1 index buffer for triangles. But the mesh has 2 seperated objects at least. For example there are 2 quads with no vertex shared (and with no index shared of course) and their geometry is in 1 single mesh (1 vertex buffer, 1 index buffer). So how can I create 2 meshes from them. Is there any algorithm for that.

I've tried to add first vertex in a new mesh then look for index which points this vertex, then I add this index and its related 2 indices (and vertices) of triangle to new mesh but indices must be changed.

I am sorry for missing info about my question. I ment seperating logicaly. For example in programming. If one single mesh in below has unshared submeshes like in the picture. I want it seperated in to 2 mesh classes. I want an algorithm a mathematical solution for that, not a tool doing this for me.

[image: Mesh partitioning]

Comment: what 3D App are you using if that's the case.

Comment: I am working with Unity but it is not important for me

Comment: It would be a simple task to do in Maya for example, never worked with unity. I am not sure if you can edit the mesh or if it's procedurally generated (?)

Comment: What are you going to do with the meshes? If you want to draw them, I would advice to leave the vertex buffer untouched and just create two separate index buffers. If you need the vertex data on the GPU anyway, there is no reason to have it in two separate buffers. Splitting could be done with a union-find data structure.

Comment: It must be done, not for drawing only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, initialize a union-find data structure with the number of vertices. Then find all connected components as follows:

```
for each triangle index i1, i2, i3 in indices
    union-find.union(i1, i2)
    union-find.union(i1, i3)
```

Then initialize an empty map (or dictionary) that will map old vertex indices to new ones:

```
Dictionary<int, int> indexMap;
```

Furthermore, we will need new lists for vertices:

```
Dictionary<int, List<Vertex>> vertices;
Dictionary<int, List<int>> indices;
```

Then distribute the vertices to the correct lists as follows:

```
for i from 0 to vertex count -1
    componentRepresentative := union-find.find(i)
    if(!vertices.ContainsKey(componentRepresentative))
        vertices.Add(new List<Vertex>());
        indices.Add(new List<int>());
    var list = vertices[componentRepresentative];
    list.Add(vertexBuffer[i]);
    indexMap.Add(i, list.Count - 1)
```

At this point we have separated the vertex buffers. We still need to separate the index buffers similarly.

```
for i from 0 to index count - 1
    componentRepresentative := union-find.find(indexbuffer[i])
    var list = indices[componentRepresentative]
    list.Add(indexMap[indexBuffer[i]])
```

Overall time complexity is nearly O(n) (for an ideal union-find structure).