# Seperate list / mesh into sub-lists / sub-meshes

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm, mesh

*EDIT: To give an idea of what type of mesh I have:*

*Imagine a LEGO brick with four knobs on the top. I read a STL file containing the surface of the whole brick. After identifying all nodes with unique coordinates (and saving their next neighbours in a list) I cut away most of the brick, so that only the four knobs remain. Unluckily for me, these four knobs are still in one big list (one for the nodes, one for the next neighbours). I want the fastest way to get all nodes of one knob if I specify one node which I know belongs to that knob.*

I have a (relatively) big `List<cNode> nodes` where

```
class cNode
{
    int nodeNumber;
    cVector vector;
}
```

and an even bigger (ca. 14e6 entries) `List<cNodeCoincidence> coincidences` where

```
class cNodeCoincidence
{
    cNode node1;
    cNode node2;
}
```

My nodes represent points in 3D and my coincidences resembles what was formerly a mesh consisting of triangles, condensed from a STL file. I know for a fact (and the user made his input accordingly), that my node-mesh is actually 4 seperate meshes in one node/coincidence list. My goal is to extract the nodes of each sub-mesh to its own nodelist. To achieve this, I start with one node for each sub-mesh, which I know to be part of said sub-mesh. Cue a recursive function:

```
private void AssembleSubMesh(ReadOnlyCollection<cNode> in_nodesToRead, List<cNode> in_nodesAlreadyRead)
{
    List<cNode> newNodesToRead = new List<cNode>();
    List<cNodeCoincidence> foundCoincidences = coincidences.Where(x => (in_nodesToRead.Any(y => y == x.node1)) || in_nodesToRead.Any(z => z == x.node2)).ToList();
    in_nodesAlreadyRead.AddRange(in_nodesToRead);
    List<cNode> allRemainingNodes = new List<cNode>();
    foreach (cNodeCoincidence nc in foundCoincidences)
    {
        allRemainingNodes.Add(nc.node1);
        allRemainingNodes.Add(nc.node2);
    }
    allRemainingNodes = allRemainingNodes.Distinct().ToList();
    allRemainingNodes.RemoveAll(x => in_nodesAlreadyRead.Contains(x));
    if (allRemainingNodes.Count != 0)
        AssembleSubMesh(new ReadOnlyCollection<cNode>(allRemainingNodes), in_nodesAlreadyRead);
}
```

which is called by: `AssembleSubMesh(new ReadOnlyCollection<cNode>(firstNodeIKnow), globalResultListForSubmesh);` thus writing the results of the recursion to a more global list.

This procedure works (tested with small mesh), but is painfully slow (over 15 hours before I aborted the process).

*Is there any way to seperate the mesh in a faster and perhaps more elegant way?*

I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571624/separating-mesh) and had a look at [this lecture](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/AlgsDS07/01UnionFind.pdf) and it seems, that there might be a chance that this (especially WQUPC) is what I need, but I don't understand how exactly it could help, because they only have a node list and I additionally have the coincidence list which would be a shame not to use, really (?).

Could a database help (because of indexing)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to identify *edge*. which is a a single connection between 2 vertices (no more other connections found). I assume that there are all vertices for all triangles, so they are duplicated. It depends on the dimension of your mesh sure, but it *shouldn't* take so much time.

You need to define dictionaries, which will pump your app's memory, but will also dramatically increase speed with guaranteed O(1) access.

In short:

1) load data

2) scan it and construct appropriate data structures 
If you observe any CAD modelling software it takes much more time then it should during loading of meshes, for the same reason: they need to scan data loaded and construct appropriate data structures to be able to process that data after as fast as it possible.

3) use those data structures to get information you need as fast as it possible.

So choose data structures and keys wisely, to meet requirements of *your* application.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't help very much. My `coincidences` list is effectively a list of edges, where every edge occures once and only once. I was rather looking for a way to get my information as fast as posible and not to get the information that I have to get the information...

Comment: @lhiapgpeonk: so do you have relationship between `openedge` and vertex ?

Comment: what is openedge? Every entry in `coincidences` consists of two verices being connected to each other i.e. lie on the same edge.

Comment: @lhiapgpeonk: so the `openedge` is the fact that *there is no other  same 2 vertices* in collection of connected vertices. if there is only one pair, that is an "open edge".

Comment: I had `coincidences` built from triangles, so for every triangle I specify three edges consisting of two vertices. I two triangles share an edge they also share the two vertices forming that edge. Since that edge would be in `coincidences` twice I delete it until only one edge remains. By defining a conincidence always with node1 being the node with the smaller number, I catch all double edges.

Comment: Ok, that means that you have already egdes collection, and you can identify the vertices that are part of the edge, and other vertices that are *not* edge, but still in the 3D bounding box of the edge vertices found.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66272/discussion-between-lhiapgpeonk-and-tigran).

Comment: So you *should* be able to identify clouds of vertices, which (assuming that this is not a scanner data, so there is no noise) will lead to having separate meshes.