# Separating unconnected objects of a model

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, helix-3d-toolkit

If anybody cares, I'm using Helix-Toolkit + WPF.

I got a 3D model generated by the marching cubes algorithm. I got the model in the form of a large `Point3D[]`. The model has some floating objects around it, and I want to separate each of those floating objects to make a `List<Point3D[]>`, where each `Point3D[]` represents a single floating object. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27318002/seperate-list-mesh-into-sub-lists-sub-meshes), but it got no correct answers. To clarify a bit more, you may imagine the following:

> Imagine a LEGO brick with four knobs on the top. I read an STL file containing the surface of the whole brick. I cut away most of the brick, so that only the four knobs remain. Unluckily for me, these four knobs are still in one big list, and I want a way of getting all the `Point3D`s of each knob separately.

Comment: If you only have the points then you have not enough information. An object is defined by connected points. So you are missing which point is connected to any other points. With that information you can seperate the four objects described by the points and their connections

Comment: Think of a cube which has 8 points (A-H) and connections between (A-B, A-D, A-E, B-C, B-F, ...). That will describe the cube. The points only describe some points without any relations

Comment: Each 3 points are connected as a triangle. For example, the three points `MyArr[0]`, `MyArr[1]` and `MyArr[2]` form a triangle. That's how WPF's `MeshGeometry3D.Positions` array is formatted @SirRufo .

Comment: Well then split the list into these triangle parts and check which of the other triangles have 2 equal points.